# Kerberos keytab file generation error: "Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' / Warning: Unable to set SPN mapping data"

Tags: kerberos, keytab, ktpass

I am trying to generate a keytab file for kerberos setup.  I keep getting an error "Failed to set property "ServicePrinciplalName.""

My call Looks like this:

```
ktpass -out ssowebapp.keytab -princ HTTP/pdx-kerbtest@DEV
-COMPANY.LOCAL -mapUser webapp5@DEV-COMPANY.LOCAL -crypto AES256-SHA1 -pType KRB5_
NT_PRINCIPAL -pass password -mapOp set
```

When I run it I get this return:

```
Targeting domain controller: DC1.dev-COMPANY.local
Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' to 'HTTP/pdx-kerbtest' on Dn 'CN=S
SO WEBAPP5,OU=Ken OU,DC=dev-COMPANY,DC=local': 0x13.
WARNING: Unable to set SPN mapping data.
If webapp5 already has an SPN mapping installed for HTTP/pdx-kerbtest, this is n
o cause for concern.
Password successfully set!
Key created.
Output keytab to ssowebapp.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 85 HTTP/pdx-kerbtest@DEV-COMPANY.LOCAL ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 67
 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) keylength 32 (0xf5873e603d459d34cc3346f672bb4e72189328
256eecc9aed4363b5c121f1b41)
```

There isn't a current mapping.  I am logged in as an administrator that is a member of Domain Admins, Schema Admins, Enterprise Admins, and the built-in Administrators group.  CMD window is ran as an administrator.  The UAC on the server is disabled.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here or what else I need to check to get this to run correctly.